# Find and replace $VARIABLE$ in files with powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm making a simple powershell script to replace SubWCRev in our environment. So I have a lot of template files containing variables like `$WCREV$` and so forth.

I'm can't do a simple find and replace on those variables though.. I'm unable to escape the $-character properly.

The find-and-replace is simple;

```
function FindAndReplace {
param(
    [string]$inputFile, 
    [string]$outputFile,
    [string]$findString, 
    [string]$replaceString)
    (Get-Content $inputFile) | foreach {$_ -replace $findString, $replaceString} |
    Set-Content $outputFile
}
```

And I've tried many alternatives for the $findString..

Tried;

```
$findString = '$WCREV$'
$findString = '`$WCREV`$'
$findString = "`$WCREV`$"
$findString = "$WCREV$"
```

Can't make any of it work. If I try just WCREV it replaces it alright, but then I'm left with the $ of course.. I guess I could modify my templates but it seems like a silly little problem so it's probably doable, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `-replace` which supports regex. `$` is the end of line anchor there. If you don't need regex then just use the string method replace instead.

```
$findString = '$WCREV$'
(Get-Content $inputFile) | foreach {$_.replace($findString,$replaceString)}
```

To make your original `$findString` with your code then you would need to use *regex escape characters* which is the backslash for PowerShell it is the backtick like you were trying. The single quotes is important to prevent PowerShell from attempting to expand the string as a variable. Either of the following would work but my first snippet is what I suggest.

```
$findString = '\$WCREV\$'
$findString = [regex]::Escape('$WCREV$')
```

Comment: Great, thanks! :) (I should've read the documentation a bit more...)